# error: 'iniziaScheda1' was not declared in this scope

Tags: c++, arduino

I looked for a month for the answer for the question below, but I din't find it, so here there is my problem:
I wrote a library for Arduino, Following is my code, the compiler always shows

```
error: 'iniziaScheda1' was not declared in this scope
```

and the same error for the other function, what can I do?

CNC.h

```
#ifndef CNC
#define CNC

#include <Arduino.h>


class CNCa
{ 
    private:
        int  latchPin1;
        int  clockPin1;
        int  dataPin1;
        int  latchPin2;
        int  clockPin2;
        int  dataPin2;
        byte scheda[7]; 
        int count;

    public: 
    void iniziaScheda1(int latch,int clock,int data);
        void iniziaScheda2 (int latch,int clock,int data);

        void motoreZ(int nStep);
        void motoreX(int nStep);
        void motoreY(int nStep);
        void motore4(int nStep);
        int velocita;
        void registro(int nScheda, byte motore);
    };
#endif
```

CNC.cpp

```
#include <CNC.h>
#include <Arduino.h>


void CNCa:: iniziaScheda1(int latch,int clock,int data){
    latchPin1=latch;
    clockPin1=clock;
    dataPin1=data;
    pinMode(latchPin1, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(clockPin1, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(dataPin1, OUTPUT);
  scheda= {    B01100000,  // = 0
                              B01010000,  // = 1
                              B00011000,  // = 2
                              B00101000,  // = 3
                              B10000100,  // = 4
                              B00000110,  // = 5
                              B00000011,  // = 6
                              B10000001,  // = 7
                              };

}

void CNCa::iniziaScheda2(int latch,int clock,int data){
    latchPin2=latch;
    clockPin2=clock;
    dataPin2=data;
    pinMode(latchPin2, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(clockPin2, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(dataPin2, OUTPUT);

}
//n Scheda indica la scheda che stiamo usando
void CNCa::registro(int nScheda, byte motore){
    if(nScheda=1){
        digitalWrite(latchPin1, LOW);    

  shiftOut(dataPin1, clockPin1, LSBFIRST,scheda[motore]);  

  digitalWrite(latchPin1, HIGH);

    }else{(digitalWrite(latchPin2, LOW);    

   shiftOut(dataPin2, clockPin2, LSBFIRST,scheda[motore]);  

    digitalWrite(latchPin2, HIGH);
}}

//i motori sono nominati come Z(scheda1 motore1) x(scheda1 motore2) y(scheda2 motore1) 4(scheda2 motore2)

void CNCa:: motoreZ (int nStep){if(nStep>0){ count=0; for(int i=0;i<nStep;i++){delay(velocita);
   switch(count){
    case 0 : registro(1,3);count++;break; 
    case 1 : registro(1,2);count++;break;
    case 2 : registro(1,1);count++;break; 
    case 3 : registro(1,0);count=0;break; 
    } ;
   }
   }else if(nStep<0){count=0;for(int i=0;i>nStep;--i){delay(velocita);
   switch(count){
    case 0 : registro(1,0);count++;break; 
    case 1 : registro(1,1);count++;break;
    case 2 : registro(1,2);count++;break; 
    case 3 : registro(1,3);count=0;break; 
    } ;
   }
    }
    }

    void CNCa:: motoreX(int nStep){if(nStep>0){ count=0; for(int i=0;i<nStep;i++){delay(velocita);
   switch(count){
    case 0 : registro(1,7);count++;break; 
    case 1 : registro(1,6);count++;break;
    case 2 : registro(1,5);count++;break; 
    case 3 : registro(1,4);count=0;break; 
    } ;
   }
   }else if(nStep<0){count=0;for(int i=0;i>nStep;--i){delay(velocita);
   switch(count){
    case 0 : registro(1,4);count++;break; 
    case 1 : registro(1,5);count++;break;
    case 2 : registro(1,6);count++;break; 
    case 3 : registro(1,7);count=0;break; 
    } ;
   }    }
    }
    void CNCa:: motoreY(int nStep){if(nStep>0){ count=0; for(int i=0;i<nStep;i++){delay(velocita);
   switch(count){
    case 0 : registro(1,3);count++;break; 
    case 1 : registro(1,2);count++;break;
    case 2 : registro(1,1);count++;break; 
    case 3 : registro(1,0);count=0;break; 
    } ;
   }
   }else if(nStep<0){count=0;for(int i=0;i>nStep;--i){delay(velocita);
   switch(count){
    case 0 : registro(2,0);count++;break; 
    case 1 : registro(2,1);count++;break;
    case 2 : registro(2,2);count++;break; 
    case 3 : registro(2,3);count=0;break; 
    } ;
   }
    }
    }

    void CNCa:: motore4(int nStep){if(nStep>0){ count=0; for(int i=0;i<nStep;i++){delay(velocita);
   switch(count){
    case 0 : registro(2,7);count++;break; 
    case 1 : registro(2,6);count++;break;
    case 2 : registro(2,5);count++;break; 
    case 3 : registro(2,4);count=0;break; 
    } ;
   }
   }else if(nStep<0){count=0;for(int i=0;i>nStep;--i){delay(velocita);
   switch(count){
    case 0 : registro(2,4);count++;break; 
    case 1 : registro(2,5);count++;break;
    case 2 : registro(2,6);count++;break; 
    case 3 : registro(2,7);count=0;break; 
    } ;
   }    }
    }
```

arduino file

```
#include <CNC.h>


void setup() {
 iniziaScheda1(1,2,3);// put your setup code here, to run once:
velocita=20;
}

void loop() {
  motoreZ(50);
  delay(1000);
  motoreZ(-50);
  delay(1000);// put your main code here, to run repeatedly:

}
```

Comment: As it is your code cannot compile. In CNC.cpp the line `}else{(digitalWrite(latchPin2, LOW);` has one left parens too many. Learn to use ctrl-T to properly indent your code (and know where you messed up).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your functions are class members, so you should create class instance and then call members on it ie.:

```
CNCa tmp;
tmp.iniziaScheda1(1,2,3);
```

To preserve values of class member variables your class instance should have global scope.